# Where to save a configuration file uploaded by admin?

Tags: java, tomcat, spring-mvc, configuration

I am working on a web application, developed using spring mvc and server is tomcat. Now one of the requirement is that admin can upload a spring related service configuration file(which is different from the spring service configuration file residing in src code) with some changes because we want to make it configurable. Now server will be restarted to get the modified changes.

Now I am confused about one thing, where I should upload this file(file system?) so that when server is started then configured listener will pick up new configuration file.

Pls suggest solution considering it as enterprose aplication.

Comment: How about the `conf` folder?!

Comment: Note that Tomcat will delete everything in your deployment directory when you undeploy the webapp. Don't consider anything in the webapps/ directory safe (and beware of symlinks, too).

Comment: "Enterprise" application that allows you to upload a new configuration and bounce the server via HTTP? Wow.

Answer (score 0):

1. Find out the reasonable place to keep your system files, other than in webapps/. 
   (I had kept next to log folder.)
2. Use Spring's `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` to read file locations from properties file.
3. Use same locations and Create `ApplicationContext` object, `in a factory method` (You can pass any number of files).
4. Use `getBean` on `applicationContext` object to use beans.